# Why is the Write trait implemented for &File and &TcpStream? Is it safe?

Tags: rust

All methods in the [`io::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html) trait accept `&mut self`. It makes sense since conceptually it needs to mutate some internal state. For the same reason, it is only natural to see it has a blanket implementation for [`&mut W`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html#impl-Write-17) if `W` is `io::Write`:

> `impl<'_, W: Write + ?Sized> Write for &'_ mut W`

On the other hand, I find it strange that it is also implemented for [`&File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html#impl-Write-10) and [`&TcpStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html#impl-Write-11) in addition to [`File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html#impl-Write) and [`TcpStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html#impl-Write-6) themselves.

This discrepancy bothers me a little bit. Is it done only for convenience? Or is it the nature of I/O make this safe?

---

Noticed this when trying out [crate `may`](https://crates.io/crates/may), a stackful coroutines library. Its [`net::TcpStream`](https://docs.rs/may/0.3.16/may/net/struct.TcpStream.html) doesn't have `io::Write` implemented for `&TcpStream`. So some code suddenly failed to compile:

```
use may::{coroutine::scope, go};  // may = "0.3"
use std::{
    error::Error,
    io::Write,
    net::TcpStream,
};

fn send_to_peer(msg: &str, peer: &TcpStream) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>
{
    scope(|scope| {
        go!(scope, move || {
            let mut socket = peer;
            let _ = socket.write_all(msg.as_bytes());
        });
    });

    Ok(())
}
```

This compiles. Switch to `may::net::TcpStream` and it will fail.

Comment: It is safe to write to a file while holding a shared reference. The in-process state of the file won't change, and the kernel takes care of concurrent access to the state of the file descriptor in the kernel. If the `Write` implementation did not exist, you'd need a mutex to write to a log file from multiple threads, making the performance worse than it needed to be.

Comment: I don't like it either, but that "safe". interior mutability is evil IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasn't intended to answer my own question, but @SvenMarnach's comment prompted me to check out the POSIX standard with respect to API thread safety. It addresses my core concern.

Specifically, the [section 2.9.1](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_01) of its 2018 edition reads:

> All functions defined by this volume of POSIX.1-2017 shall be thread-safe, except that the following functions need not be thread-safe.

And `write` is not among them. Furthermore, [section 2.9.7](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_07) dictates:

> All of the following functions shall be atomic with respect to each other in the effects specified in POSIX.1-2017 when they operate on regular files or symbolic links

And `write` should be atomic to other listed APIs.

Because of this thread-safety at operating system level, the Rust language level constructions, namely a value, its (shared) reference and its mutable (exclusive) reference get subsumed; they are all semantically thread-safe here.

The implementation of `io::Write` for `&File` and `&TcpStream` then serves as an optimization. Otherwise, one would need a Mutex to write to them from multiple threads, which introduces unnecessary overhead.